# Is there a purpose to the scene where Dog finds a kid in Denerim?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

In *Dragon Age: Origins*, there is a scene where Dog finds a boy in Denerim. (Note that despite the video title, there are no spoilers).

Is there a purpose to this scene? Does anything happen depending on the dialogue options you choose? Does this have any effect later?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's a comedic scene. Instead of the boy bringing home a dog, your dog brings home a boy.

*Get it?*

Comment: Did a quick search to see if it affected affinity with Dog or something. Every forum says this. One was basically word for word. Disappointing, and not actually funny.

Comment: @DCShannon Agreed, it's too short and would have been better if they had Dog dragging the boy by his pants or something...I dunno.

Comment: You can stretch out the scene by choosing dialogue options like "Well he'll have to fight darkspawn", <whimper>, "...yes, he's too young, that's my point". Still, I agree that it could have been rewritten to be funnier and not so much out of nowhere.

Comment: @DCShannon Dog's affinity is always 100%, so if there was an effect, it would be something else.